# How can I perform an addition on a column based on a condition which changes per row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data handling question that I hope someone could help with.

I have two columns in a dataframe:

```
A               B
111            5.2
EF             5.6
DG             5.1
LK             5.4
111            5
EF             5.2
```

I want to make a 3rd column C where everytime 111 is shown in column a, I want to take the difference from 5 away from Column B until the next 111 is shown.

So it would look like this

```
A               B            C
111            5.2         5 (minus 0.2)
EF             5.6         5.4 (minus 0.2)
DG             5.1         4.9 (minus 0.2
LK             5.4         5.2 (minus 0.2)
111            5            5 (no change needed as already 5)
EF             5.2          5.2 (no change needed as previous 111 already 5)
```

So if 111 in column A has a value in Column B of 5.2 then (5-5.2=-0.2) Therefore C=5.2 + -0.2 = 5
If 111 in Column A has a value in Column B of 4.8 then (5-4.8=0.2) Therefore C=4.8+0.2 = 5
Etc until the next 111 is found.

Hopefully this makes sense. Essentially 111 is a standard that should be 5. If it is not 5 then I want to apply the difference to all over values in Row B until a new 111 is found.
Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: And should the same apply to the next 111 that is found?

Comment: Exactly. Each time a new 111 is found, a calculation is done to see how far away it is from 5, then this is used to make changes to the rest of the rows until a new 111 is found. This then should repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should just be able to use `np.where` and `ffill`

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] == '111', 5 - df['B'], np.nan)
df['C'] = df['C'].ffill()
df['C'] = df['B'] - abs(df['C'])


     A    B    C
0  111  5.2  5.0
1   EF  5.6  5.4
2   DG  5.1  4.9
3   LK  5.4  5.2
4  111  5.0  5.0
5   EF  5.2  5.2
```

Comment: Check your output

Comment: This worked great! Thank you very much. I have learn a new function .ffil (forward fill) really useful!

Answer (score 3):

I am using `transform` after create the groupkey with `cumsum`

```
df['C']=df.B-(df.groupby(df.A.eq('111').cumsum()).B.transform('first')-5)
df
Out[662]: 
     A    B    C
0  111  5.2  5.0
1   EF  5.6  5.4
2   DG  5.1  4.9
3   LK  5.4  5.2
4  111  5.0  5.0
5   EF  5.2  5.2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

This looks like a very sophisticated method, I will read about the different functions you used.